# SVG filterRes alternative/replacement strategy

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, svg-filters

When you create an SVG with a shadow, then zoom in/out on your SVG you'll get some serious performance issues due to re-computing the shadows.

In the past, you could use [filterRes=''](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/filterRes) to get around this. However, filterres has been deprecated and removed from the SVG spec.

I'm seeking an alternative to [filterRes=''](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/filterRes), which will allow me to work with things like SVG shadows in a performant way when doing things like zooming in/out which causes shadows to be re-computed.

---

Does anyone have any experience overcoming performance obstacle that surfaced once filterres was deprecated? Any examples of strategies for replacing the functionality that filterres use to provide?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do, is to render the shadow to an image an include that in your svg. Starting from that there could be solutions which generate that shadow in different resolutions and pull in the appropriate size on demand. You could as well use a `<canvas>` to create the shadow client side and hand it over to the svg as base64 encoded image source.

It strongly depends on your application and the performances requirements, so it can be sufficient to have three or for "steps of resultion" pre rendered, or something more complicated needs to be applied...

Btw. You can also reference the `<filter>` element  with Javascript and manipulate the filter attributes directly...

Answer (score 0):

If you can convince the browser to do scaling on the GPU rather than the CPU, this will make things far more performant, so using CSS 3D Transforms rather than JavaScript or viewBox animation to zoom in and out on SVG may do the trick.